# How can I maintain a a dropdown's current information without repopulating the list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Currently, I have a drop down list that is populated with team names from a SQL database:

```
$(".show_hide2").click(function () {
    ("#team").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
    $(".slidingDiv2").slideToggle();
    teams = $.parseJSON(getTeams());
    for (i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
        var team = getTeam(teams[i]);
        updateTeamBoard(team);
        populateTeamSelection(team);
    }
}
```

Here's the code for populating the dropdown.

JS:

```
function populateTeamSelection(team) {
    var team = $.parseJSON(team);
    $("#teamSelection").find("#tr:gt(0)").remove();
    $("<option value='" + team.teamID + "'>" + team.teamName + "</option>").appendTo("#teamSelection");
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slidingDiv2">
    <select id="teamSelection">
        <option id="default" value="0">Select A Team</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="teamViewer" value="Team Viewer"></input>
</div>
```

The problem is, every time I click the show/hide button, it retains the current information in the list and then adds the same information to the list. I'm using AJAX to dynamically generate tables and lists, but for some reason I just can't figure this out and I have a feeling it's rather simple. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited it for readability.

Comment: Can you try $("#teamSelection").html("<option value='" + team.teamID + "'>" + team.teamName + "</option>"); instead of $("<option value='" + team.teamID + "'>" + team.teamName + "</option>") .appendTo("#teamSelection"); in function populateTeamSelection(team) ??

Comment: Also give a sample of your team json, and the html feilds you are tryign to update. its hard to connect the dots here

Comment: {"teamID":101,"teamName":"TeamRockers","ownerID":1,"minTeamSize":2,"maxTeamSize":6,"active":true,"enrollmentCutOff":1222243500}

Comment: HTML and JSON added. Basically, the team selection is inside a div that is shown after an onclick event. But, since that onclick triggers the populateTeamSelection function, it just keeps populating the <select> with the same information, every time you show/hide the div. Also, I tried your suggestion and it only gave me one result in the options. But, it did maintain that state, so I'd say it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Is it necessary for you to request the teams through ajax every time you show/hide? Can't you request it once and reuse the same information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you click, `populateTeamSelection()` gets called. Every time `populateTeamSelection()` gets called, it appends something to the list. A quick fix is to delete all the items from the list before adding any of them.

You can use `$('select').children().remove()` to delete all the `option` items before your `for` loop.

Comment: And that works! Thanks very much, I'm still pretty new at this.

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, refer to [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) so you can better format your posts in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function ($)
{
    $populateTeamSelection = function(team)
    {
        $result = $.parseJSON(team,function(call){$handle = call;});
        $result.success(function(){ $data = $handle; });
        $result.error(function()
        {
            //Do something or nothing on error
        });
        $result.complete(function()
        {
            //Clear all current options first
            $('#teamSelection').html('');

            //Populate with new data
            $.each($data,function(lable,value)
            {
                $("#teamSelection").append($("<option></option>").attr("value",value['teamID']).text(value['teamName']));
            });
        });
    };
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.show_hide2').click(function()
    {
        $(".slidingDiv2").slideToggle();
        $populateTeamSelection(team);
    });
});
```

Comment: You could also change it to: $.fn.populateTeamSelection = function, Then replace $('#teamSelection') with $(this), This way you can run it in .ready like so: $('#teamSelection').populateTeamSelection(team);